# Как отправить отчет на эл. почту с помощью VBA?

Tags: база-данных, администрирование, vba, office, ms-access

У меня есть выпадающий список с id_students и кнопка. Как сформировать отчет по id_students и вложить его в письмо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать требуемый отчёт. В источнике данных в условии отбора написать соотв. выражение отбора по значению контрола формы. Далее создать макрос с 2 командами. Первая - ОткрытьОтчет, в качестве параметров открытие созданного отчёта (можно скрытым - на экране-то он не нужен). Вторая - ОтправитьОбъект, в качестве параметров указать открытый отчёт и данные адресата. "Повесить" макрос на кнопку формы. Всё. Ну разве что ещё закрыть отчёт, если он больше ни для чего не нужен.